# substring max 25 chars keeping the end of string if match the pattern

Tags: php, regex, substring

I have a string that can be like this:

```
$string = 'namestring';
```

Or
    $string = 'namestring_1';

Namestring can be everything and can or not be followed by underscore + number.

I need to check if the string length is more of 25 chars and if it is truncate only the part of the namestring keeping the underscore+number if there is so the total length will be 25 chars.

Example:

```
$string ='012345678901234567890123456789_6';
$string2 ='012345678901234567890123456789';
```

Has to change in:

```
$string ='01234567890123456789012_6';
$string2 ='0123456789012345678901234';
```

Can you help me please?

Edit:
Sorry...I didn't think to specify it. Not necessarily only one digit even if it is very rare for it to be two digits after the underscore.

Comment: Post some of the code you've tried, even if (especially if) it's not working.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by `I need to check if the string length is more of 25 chars and if it is truncate only the part of the namestring keeping the underscore+number if there is so the total length will be 25 chars.` -- could you explain?

Comment: Is the number after the underscore always an only digit?

Comment: Sorry...I didn't think to specify it. Not necessarily only one digit even if it is very rare for it to be two digits after the underscore.

Comment: Amal... I'm sorry but I don't know how to explain better than this.. my english is not so good. If you have a question I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a working solution for you if only a single digit can follow after the underscore.  Otherwise, you just need to modify it so 23 becomes `25 - strlen($match[1])`.

```
if (preg_match('/(_\d)$/', $namestring, $match)) {
    $namestring = substr(0, 23, $namestring) . $match[1];
} else {
    $namestring = substr(0, 25);
}
```

Comment: Like this?

`if (preg_match('(_\d)$', $namestring, $match)) {
    $namestring = substr(0, 25 - strlen($match[1]), $namestring) . $match[1];
} else {
    $namestring = substr(0, 25);
}`

Comment: I tried to test it... but it gives me the error "preg_match(): Unknown modifier '$'" ... I don't understand why.

Comment: @user2980264 sorry fixed now, forgot the delimiters around the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

The ugly regex solution from the mountain (for only 1 digit after the underscore):

```
$result = preg_replace('~^.{23}\K(?(?!.*_\d$)(.{2})).*(_\d)?$~', '$1$2', $str);
```

Pattern detail:

I use a conditional inside (IF...THEN...): `(?(?!.*_\d$)(.{2}))`

```
(?             # IF
  (?!.*_\d$)   # (CONDITION): if there is not _\d at the end
  (.{2})       # THEN: capture two other characters
)              # ENDIF
```

or better with a branch reset `(?|..|..)`:

```
$result = preg_replace('~^\d{23}\K(?|.*(_\d)|(.{2}).*)$~', '$1', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string ='012345678901234567890123456789_6';
$string2 ='012345678901234567890123456789';
$string3 ='0123456_78901234567890123456789';
$c = explode("_", $string, 2);
$fixed = (count($c) > 1 ? (((strlen($c[0]) > 23) ? (substr($c[0],0,strlen($c[0]))) : substr((substr($c[0],0,23) . "_" . $c[1]),0,25))) : substr($c[0],0,25));
```

This works regardless of what the input.

**Output**

- For $string = "01234567890123456789012_6"
- For $string2 = "0123456789012345678901234"
- For $string3 = "0123456_78901234567890123"

Answer (score 0):

Why not use substr()?
Here is how I would do it:

```
$str= "67676767676767676766767675757675757575757575746655_2";
$pos = strpos($str,"_");

$end = substr($str, $pos-strlen($str));

$start = substr($str, 25-strlen($pos));

$your_string = $start.$end;
```

Edit: from all 4 answers, only mine would work if you have a 2-digit figure after the _ :)

Comment: Thank you, it's true it works with a two-digit figure but it works even with letters after the underscore e.g. '_abc' and it's a mess with a string like this `$str = '1234567890123_456aaattttv vvvbbbbeeee llllsssiiic cchjhhdd d78901cccc8901';` - I know it's a stupid string but it can be! :)

Comment: @user2980264 That's right. Maybe you can specify a bit more about your string so that I can see what specifications the string has. If it is really all random, what use does the string have for you. Why do you need it shortened to a length of 25?  With more data I can review my answer accordingly.